# Substraction in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fixed-point

I am working on a Verilog fixed point adder, using which I will also do the subtraction. When I do the subtraction not always I get the correct result.

For example, 1-1=0, but I get -0.

Kindly have a look on the below mentioned code:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module adder #(
//Parameterized values
parameter Q = 27,
parameter N = 32
)
(
input [N-1:0] a,
input [N-1:0] b,
output [N-1:0] c
);

reg [N-1:0] res;

assign c = res;

always @(a,b) begin
// both negative or both positive
if(a[N-1] == b[N-1]) begin              //Since they have the same sign, absolute magnitude increases
    res[N-2:0] = a[N-2:0] + b[N-2:0];   //So just the two numbers are added
    res[N-1] = a[N-1];                  //and the sign is set appropriately...       
    end     
//  one of them is negative...
else if(a[N-1] == 0 && b[N-1] == 1) begin           //  subtracts a-b
    if( a[N-2:0] > b[N-2:0] ) begin                 //  if a is greater than b,
        res[N-2:0] = a[N-2:0] - b[N-2:0];   
        res[N-1] = 0;                               //  manually the sign is set to positive
        end
    else begin                                      //  if a is less than b,
        res[N-2:0] = b[N-2:0] - a[N-2:0];           // subtracting a from b to avoid a 2's complement answer
        if (res[N-2:0] == 0)
            res[N-1] = 0;                          //   To remove negative zero....
        else
            res[N-1] = 1;                         //        and manually the sign is set to negative
        end
    end
else begin                                       // subtract b-a (a negative, b positive)
    if( a[N-2:0] > b[N-2:0] ) begin             //  if a is greater than b,
        res[N-2:0] = a[N-2:0] - b[N-2:0];       //      subtracting b from a to avoid a 2's complement answer
        if (res[N-2:0] == 0)
            res[N-1] = 0;                                       
        else
            res[N-1] = 1;                       //      and manually the sign is set to negative
        end
    else begin                                 //   if a is less than b,
        res[N-2:0] = b[N-2:0] - a[N-2:0];       
        res[N-1] = 0;                                   
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```

Testbench for the adder is below:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module tb_adder (
);

reg clk;
reg [ 31 : 0 ] a;
reg [ 31 : 0 ] b;

wire [ 31: 0 ] c;

adder adder_i (
    .a(a),
    .b(b),
    .c(c)
    );

parameter CLKPERIODE = 100;

initial clk = 1'b1;
always #(CLKPERIODE/2) clk = !clk;

initial begin

$monitor ("adder=%h", c);

#1
    a = 32'h08000000;
    b = 32'hF8000000;

  #(CLKPERIODE)
  $finish();

end

endmodule
```

I am having a hard time to find where did I go wrong as I am a newbie in Verilog. I am using this module to calculate Taylor Series in Fixed Point arithmetic. Any suggestions?

Comment: In a twos-complement number there is no such thing as -0. Which means your code is wrong. Why are you trying to re-invent subtraction? Just use a signed vector and the - operator will do it all for you and it will NOT make a mistake.

Comment: where exactly are you getting `-0` from? Which tool reports it? In any case there is no such thing in verilog, as the previous comment explained. you should be able to dislpaty binary/hex numbers in verilog to understand what is going on.

Comment: even when you reinvent the subtraction for education purpose, it's overly complex. An [adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)) needs only a xor and an and gate

Comment: From your implementation, it seems you are assuming the inputs are in sign+magnitude format. Unless there is a really, really good reason to do this, you should rather use two's complement as others here point out. This will give you addition / subtraction etc. out-of-the-box in Verilog.

Comment: -0 only exists in one's compliment. `a - b` is the same as `a + twos_compliment(b)`. The best part is it doesn't matter is `a` or `b` are represented as two's compliment positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

The only case I could find where your code produces the dirty zero is when both inputs are the dirty zero themselves. i.e.

```
a = b = 32'h80000000 = "-0"
```

It looks like this happens because in this case your code takes the branch at

```
if(a[N-1] == b[N-1]) begin              //Since they have the same sign, absolute magnitude increases
```

and this branch doesn't have the same check as the others that specifically avoids it. You could fix this by moving that code to the end of the always block so it runs no matter what branch is taken earlier.